# Python: Sub attribute in a class

Tags: python, class

It's probably a silly question, but I am stuck here. In Python I have created a class Match, with some attributes like my_match.goals, my_match.yellow_cards, etc.
I would like every match to also have some of the same attributes but restricted to the first half of the game. 
Ideally, my first thought would be a kind of sub attribute, something like

```
my_match.half_time.goals
```

but of course it doesn't work.

My question is: what would be the best data structure for such a necessity and how would I implement it? I don't think a subclass would be a good idea, because I want the same instance to be able to describe half time and full time. 
Thank you!

Comment: This is too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid using or creating another class, you can use `namedtuples` objects. Named tuple instances can be referenced using object like variable deferencing or the standard tuple syntax.

```
from collections import namedtuple
HalfTime = namedtuple('Halftime', 'goals yellow_cards')
my_match.half_time = HalfTime(4, 5)
my_match.half_time.goals
>>> 4
my_match.half_time.yellow_cards
>>> 5
```

If you want to update your values

```
my_match.half_time = my_match.half_time._replace(goals=10)
```

Comment: This is one option... however, if the OP wishes to update the values post-creation (assuming they even know the values at creation time), then the syntax isn't very intuitive or really that efficient...

Comment: Thank you this suits perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a set of statistics and maintaining separate sets of statistics for different periods of the Match.

I would implement this with a separate class of statistics and have multiple instances of that class for the different periods of the Match, including one instance that accumulates the statistics for the entire Match.  Maybe something like this:

```
class Statistics(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__goals = 0
        self.__yellow_cards =0
    def getGoals(self): return self.__goals
    def addGoal(self): self.__goals += 1
    …

class AccumulatedStatistics(object):
    def __init__(self, *statistics):
        self.__statistics = list(statistics)
    def getGoals(self):
        return reduce(lambda a,b:a.getGoals() + b.getGoals(), statistics)
    …

class Match(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.quarterStats = [Statistics(), Statistics(), Statistics(), Statistics()]
        self.halfStats = [
            AccumulatedStatistics(self.quarterStats[0], self.quarterStats[1]), 
            AccumulatedStatistics(self.quarterStats[2], self.quarterStats[3]),
        ]
        self.matchStats = AccumulatedStatistics(*self.quarterStats)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to use this class just for reading values, therefore 'namedtuple' is enough for this case.